# How to properly reduce an adverbial clause?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, expressions, conjunctions

> I know American culture very well living there for ten years.

Is this sentence understandable, or even natural? I made it myself to see if the sentence could potentially be the reduced version of the followings.

> I know American culture very well because I **have been living** there
>   for ten years.
>
> I know American culture very well because I **have lived** there for ten
>   years.
>
> I know American culture very well because I **lived** there for ten
>   years.
>
> I know American culture very well **by** living there for ten years.

I always think reducing an adverbial clause that is put at the back of the sentence would produce lots of ambiguous meanings, like the examples above. But a friend on the Internet told me that sentences like

> John saved money living in a cheap apartment.
>
> John saved money living in the U.S.
>
> John worked long hours at the hospital living in a cheap apartment.

could be easily understood as

> John saved money **by** living in a cheap apartment.
>
> John saved money **while he was** living in the U.S.
>
> John worked long hours at the hospital **while he was** living in a cheap
>   apartment.

It seems like if a sentence is natural and common enough, then reducing the adverbial clause won't make it ambiguous. I'm still trying to figure out how this works and the grammatical rules involved.

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity in your different versions; they're just different ways of elaborating on the same meaning. I find the sentence perfectly understandable, only I would prefer a comma after _well_.

Comment: @KateBunting What I meant at that part, was that reducing any of the four alternatives would cause it to possibly have the other three meanings as well. That's why it may be ambiguous to reduce the adverbial clause in any of the four alternatives.

Comment: @Sam In your second set of examples, the disambiguation is because of semantics, not grammar. The first sentence has an obvious link between  "save money" and "cheap". The second two examples have no such link and the only possible meaning is simultaneity: "while". I think the same applies to your four sentences. The only reason to include the two clauses in the same sentence is the causation, a semantic link.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty What are your thoughts on the reduced version of the four sentences? Do you see any causation in the reduced version? Thank you.

Comment: @Sam They are all grammatical. The meaning is a little different, given the use of preterite and past progressive. The last example is understandable, though it sounds a little unusual, compared to the first three. The ones that  include the word "because" obviously imply causation, and the one with "by" does too.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I'm sorry that I made you think I was talking about the four sentences. By "the reduced version of the four sentences" I mean _I know American culture very well living there for ten years._  Do you see any causation in the reduced version? And what are your thoughts on it?

Comment: Again, I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: No apology needed, my misunderstanding. I think the reduced version implies causation, just by the juxtaposition of the two clauses. I would put a comma after "well", though. Another thing, though, is that the shade of meaning from the tense in the original sentences, as to whether you are still there or were there at some time in the past, is lost in the reduced version.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty If we put a comma after "well", would the sentence become as natural as something native English speakers would write? Thank you.

Comment: I think "having lived there for ten years" is a little more natural. If you are still in America, then "having lived here for ten years" would fit.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you very much. I learned a lot.